# Is there a simpler way of creating a Django object in a view with POST parameters..

Tags: django, post, django-views

If I have the following code in a view...

```
enquiry = Enquiry(
                  name=request.POST['name'],
                  email=request.POST['email'],
                  enquiry_input=request.POST['enquiry_input'],
                  enquiry_type=request.POST['enquiry_type']
                  )

        enquiry.full_clean()
        enquiry.save()
```

is there a way I can pass all the params in at once? I know you can do this in rails. e.g. `Object.create(object_params)` is there a Django equivalent? FYI I haven't yet created a form on the frontend yet I'm just testing that a POST request creates an Enquiry object...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Python's kwargs expansion using `**` to do this:

```
enquiry = Enquiry(**kwargs)
```

But don't. This is unsafe for the same reason Rails introduced strong_params. Use a form instead.

Comment: gotcha, I was wondering if it was possible then what would be the equiv of rails strong_params. Thanks! :)

Comment: It's good to see that "use a form" caveat, but the first part of this answer might mislead people into using that approach in spite of forms.

Answer (score 1):

The correct and the easiest way is to use [model forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#django.forms.ModelForm).

```
class EnquiryForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Enquiry
        fields = ['name', 'email', 'enquiry_input', 'enquiry_type']
```

You don't have to display it to the user, you may just use it for [validation and saving](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method):

```
def my_view(request):
    form = EnquiryForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return # normally a redirect response here
    else:
        # react to incorrect data
        # you may investigate form.errors
        return # some error response
```

Comment: Model forms all the way. Here's a handy tool if you want to explore the time saving class based views, too: https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.9/django.views.generic.edit/CreateView/

With `CreateView`, you can quickly make a view that is set up to automatically create an object on POST, if the associated form is valid. You might prefer to stick with explicit function based views though. Django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#createview